# Convergence of $ \sqrt n - \sqrt{n+1} $

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence

Is this valid proof for the convergence of $ (\sqrt n - \sqrt{n+1})_{n\ge1} \\$?

$$
\frac {\sqrt n - \sqrt{n+1}} 1 \cdot \frac {\sqrt n + \sqrt{n+1}} {\sqrt n + \sqrt{n+1}} = \frac {-1} {\sqrt n + \sqrt{n+1}}
$$

Since we know that $\sqrt n > 0 ~$we can conclude that the fraction must always be negative. Therefore, since the sum of $\sqrt n + \sqrt {n+1} > \sqrt {n}~$, we can state:

$$
\frac {-1} {\sqrt n + \sqrt {n+1}} > \frac {-1} {\sqrt n}
$$

By negating we can turn the inequation around (corrected):

$$
\frac {1} {\sqrt {n} +\sqrt {n+1}} < \frac {1} {\sqrt n}
$$

Since $\frac {1}{\sqrt n}$ is greater now, the convergence of $\frac {1}{\sqrt n}$ would imply the convergence of $\sqrt n -\sqrt{n+1}$:

$$
| (\frac 1 {\sqrt n}) - 0 | = \frac 1 {\sqrt n} \le \frac 1 {\sqrt n_0} < \epsilon
$$

That would mean:

$$
n_0 > \frac {1} {\epsilon^2}
$$

In case this is valid, advice on a better and more mathematical way (less explanation) would be appreciated.

Comment: So far the responses you're getting are showing you how to prove the convergence.  However, your question was whether your proof is valid.  It is not.  There are at least a few steps that look troubling, but one in particular is when you negated the inequation.  You didn't actually negate it.  Note that $\frac{-a}{b}=\frac{a}{-b}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It suffices to say that $\sqrt n+\sqrt{n+1}$ grows unboundedly$^*$, then its inverse converges to zero.

---

$^*$ By contradiction, let $\forall n:\sqrt n\le U$. But with $n=(U+1)^2$, $\sqrt{(U+1)^2}=U+1>U$, so that $\sqrt n$ can't be bounded above (and it is a growing function).

Comment: @Arthur: you are right, I missed that nuance.

Answer (score 0):

Argue that
$$
\sqrt{n+1}=\sqrt{n\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}
$$
It comes
$$
\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n+1}=\sqrt{n}\left(1-\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}\right)=\sqrt{n}\left(1-\left(1+\frac{1}{2n}+o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)\right)
$$
Hence using that $\sqrt{1+x}\underset{(0^{+})}{=}1+\frac{1}{2x}+o\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \ $ we have
$$
\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n+1}=\sqrt{n}\left(1-\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}\right)\underset{(+\infty)}{=}-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}+o\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)
$$
That proves your result.